# Simulating the sample space for a probability problem in Python

Tags: python, statistics, probability

I am interested in simulating the sample space for the following question on a probability assignment:

> A man will carve pumpkins for his two daughters and three sons. His wife will bring each kid’s pumpkins in a completely random order. The man has decided that as soon as he has carved pumpkins for two of his sons, he would ask his wife to carve the remaining pumpkins. Let W denote the number of pumpkins he will carve.

So the resulting sample space of W would look something like this:

```
sample_space=[['S','S'],
              ['S','D','S'],
              ['S','D','D','S'],
              ['D','S','S'],
              ['D','S','D','S'],
              ['D','D','S','S']]
```

I was thinking about having two lists, one of sons, one of daughters:

```
son_list1=['S','S','S']
daughter_list1=['D','D']
```

And then combining them with in every possible order:

```
result_list1=[['S','S','S','D','D'],
              ['S','S','D','S','D'],
              ['S','S','D','D','S'],
              ['S','D','S','S','D'],
              ['S','D','S','D','S'],
              ['S','D','D','S','S'],
              ['D','S','S','S','D'],
              ['D','S','S','D','S'],
              ['D','S','D','S','S'],
              ['D','D','S','S','S']]
```

I don't know if numbering each son and each daughter and then combining them would be easier where we have:

```
son_list2=['S1','S2','S3']
daughter_list2=['D1','D2']
```

where this resulting list would be something like:

```
result_list2=[['S1','S2','S3','D1','D2'],
              ['S1','S3','S2','D1','D2'],
              ['S2','S1','S3','D1','D2'],
              ['S2','S3','S1','D1','D2'],
              ['S3','S1','S2','D1','D2'],
              ['S3','S2','S1','D1','D2'],
...
              ['D2','D1','S3','S2','S1']]
```

But if this method would be easier, I could just get rid of the numbers after `result_list2` was generaged and then delete the repeats.

Anyway, after I get the resulting list in the form of `result_list1`, I could create a "son counter" and then go through each list and then stop when the "son counter" reaches 2 and then from there delete the repeats to get the `sample_space` list.

Is there any better logic?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I think the best solution would be to get all of the permutations of the order in which he carves each pumpkin.

I just used the following code, for getting all permutations of a set, from [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-all-the-permutation-of-a-list-in-python/). I just changed some of the variable names to make it more clear.

```
def permutation(passed_list):
    # If passed_list is empty then there are no permutations
    if len(passed_list) == 0:
        return []

    # If there is only one element in lst then, only
    # one permutation is possible
    if len(passed_list) == 1:
        return [passed_list]

# Find the permutations for passed_list if there are
# more than 1 characters

perm_list = []  # empty list that will store current permutation

# Iterate the input(passed_list) and calculate the permutation
for i in range(len(passed_list)):
    item = passed_list[i]
    # Extract passed_list[i] or item from the list.  remaining_list is
    # remaining list
    remaining_list = passed_list[:i] + passed_list[i + 1:]

    # Generating all permutations where item is first
    # element
    for p in permutation(remaining_list):
        perm_list.append([item] + p)

return perm_list
```

Then you can just iterate through all of the permutations, keeping track of the order as you go. Once you get to two sons, you stop going through that iteration, add that order to your sample space, and then go to the next permutation.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Set of all children. It doesn't matter what order this list is in
    children = ['S', 'S', 'S', 'D', 'D']

    # perms is the list of all permutations of children list
    perms = permutation(children)

    # This set will hold the resulting sample space you are looking for
    total_set = []

    # For each permutation
    for perm in perms:
        order = []  # Contains the order of whose pumpkin he carves
        son_counter = 0
        for child in perm:
            if child is 'S':
                son_counter += 1
            # Update the order
            order.append(child)
            if son_counter is 2:
                # To keep from adding duplicate orders
                if order not in total_set:
                    total_set.append(order)
                # Reset the following two variables for the next iteration
            order = []
            son_counter = 0
            break

print(total_set)
```

This gave me the following output:

```
[['S', 'S'], ['S', 'D', 'S'], ['S', 'D', 'D', 'S'], ['D', 'S', 'S'], ['D', 'S', 'D', 'S'], ['D', 'D', 'S', 'S']]
```

I believe this is the answer you are looking for.

Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

You could use dynamic programming to build up the sample space from the bottom up. For example,

```
def create_samples(n_sons, n_daughters):
  if n_sons == 0:
    # stop carving
    yield []
  elif n_daughters == 0:
    # must carve n_sons more pumpkins
    yield ['S'] * n_sons
  else:
    # choose to carve for a sun
    for sample in create_samples(n_sons - 1, n_daughters):
      yield ['S'] + sample
    # choose to carve for a daughter
    for sample in create_samples(n_sons, n_daughters - 1):
      yield ['D'] + sample

samples = list(create_samples(2, 2))

# [['S', 'S'],
#  ['S', 'D', 'S'],
#  ['S', 'D', 'D', 'S'],
#  ['D', 'S', 'S'],
#  ['D', 'S', 'D', 'S'],
#  ['D', 'D', 'S', 'S']]
```

The function `create_samples(n_sons, n_daughters)` returns all samples that meet your condition, under the assumption that n_sons and n_daughters remain to be processed.